# Guaranteed rejection of citizenship application if non-dom status claimed on a previous Tier 2 work visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa, uk-citizenship

How does claiming a [non-domiciled status by origin](https://www.google.com/search?q=non+domiciled+status+by+origin+uk&oq=non+domiciled+status+by+origin+uk&aqs=chrome..69i57.1009j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in the UK while on a Tier 2 work visa affect future naturalization application? Is rejection guaranteed due to past claim of non-domicile (and hence no intent to make UK their domicile)?

Comment: Interesting question. I think it might affect naturalization but you can always change your domicile by claiming domicile of **choice**.

Comment: But what if one claims non-dom status for the majority of the time in UK (say for 4-5 years) and claims domicile by ***choice*** status  for the last 1-2 years before naturalization? How would that affect naturalization?

Comment: I would like to know that too. @phoog can you help?